# Migrating the SAN lun in Linux

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, lun

How to perform LUN migration in Linux (using LVM and native multipath) from one storage device to another storage device

Comment: Is there a chance you could tell us some of the details involved please - you've put almost zero effort into this question as it's essentially unanswerable until you do.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on janneb's comment because I want formatting:

Given:

```
/dev/oldSAN1 (Linux LVM partition)
/dev/newSAN1 (linux LVM partition)
VG "mystuff"
```

Then:

```
# pvcreate /dev/newSAN1
# vgextend mystuff /dev/newSAN1
# pvmove -v /dev/oldSAN1
# vgreduce -a mystuff
# pvremove /dev/oldSAN1
```

Obviously, make sure you have a good backup before starting. /dev/newSAN1 has to be as large as or larger than /dev/oldSAN1 as you'd think.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "pvmove" command.